# Activemodel traverse up the tree

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Models:**

```
Companies(has_many) -> (belongs_to)Clients(has_many) -> (belongs_to)Properties
```

**Getting lists going down is easily done:**

```
company.clients -> shows all clients for that company
client.properties -> show all properties for that client
```

What I want to do is to show all properties (route: properties_path) but only for 1 company and providing a link the the client in the view.

**I have several solutions:**

- Writing right outer join in sql (was using sqlite in my development env so needed postgress to get it working)

  - Brute force looping: get all clients for that company and then fetch per client all the properties in 1 hash

So my question is is there a more elegant and maybe rails way to do this that I'm missing?

**I explored include already. But this is my issue:**

```
[4] pry(main)> @company = Company.includes(clients: [:properties]).find(1)                                                                                                       
  Company Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies"  WHERE "companies"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]                                                                  
  Client Load (3.5ms)  SELECT "clients".* FROM "clients"  WHERE "clients"."company_id" IN (1)                                                                                    
  Property Load (5.9ms)  SELECT "properties".* FROM "properties"  WHERE "properties"."client_id" IN (2, 12)                                                                      
=> #<Company id: 1, name: "coolDEVOPS2", created_at: "2014-10-31 11:05:05", updated_at: "2014-11-25 09:27:38">                                                                   
[5] pry(main)>
```

I don't get properties back?

> > **SOLVED**: I'm stupid it's there irb/pry only prints the first record :)

@company.properties works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use has many through for that and rails is smart enough to work it out.

```
class Company
  has_many :clients
  has_many :properties, through: :clients
end

class Client
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :properties
end

class Property
  belongs_to :client
end

@company = Company.find(1)
@company.properties
```

But given you want a link to the client too I'm guessing you want to loop over clients and for each client show the properties, so you want eager loading

```
Company.includes(clients: [:properties]).find(1)
```

Comment: I've been exploring includes before. But even with through: :clients I only get Company data back and not properties.

Comment: Also used the .select and didn't seem to get a result... Maybe I did it wrong.

Comment: You shouldn't need the has_many through for the eager loading.